# How to store a Captured Image path in REALM?

Tags: android, database, realm

Has anyone tried to to capture an image using the camera intent, and on Activity result save it to your gallery, while your path to the image gets stored in a realm database?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm documentations say the following limitation:

`Strings` and `byte arrays` (`byte[]`) cannot be larger than 16 MB.

The recommended way is to save the path to a file instead of the actual image.